# Selecting different and common values in arrays - php function

Tags: php, arrays

What is the best way to do this. You have 2 arrays for input, let's say:

```
$current = array('strawberry', 'apple', 'banana', 'peach');
$new = array('apple', 'blackberry', 'mango', 'banana');
```

Now write a class/function that returns two arrays like:

```
$add = array('blackberry', 'mango');
$del = array('strawberry', 'peach');
```

What is the best way / the most efficient way to write function/class that performs that task?

I figured something like this:

```
function replaceTags($new, $current) {
    $tmp = array_intersect($new, $current);
    $add = array_diff($new, $tmp);
    $del = array_diff($current, $tmp);

    return array($add, $del);
}
```

Im wondering if PHP built-in functions are best for that task?
Any suggestion would be appreciate ;)

Comment: Are you alloting task to the people in stackoverflow? (i.e)without trying anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_diff($array1, $array2) returns the values in $array1 that are not in $array2.

Therefore, you could get the values that have been added using:

```
$add = array_diff($new, $current)
```

and the values that were removed using:

```
$del = array_diff($current, $new)
```